# Is there way to save trained model after overfitting occurs in CatBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I am using [CatBoostRegressor](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-reference_catboostregressor-docpage/#python-reference_catboostregressor) in Python version of the Catboost library.

According to documentation, it's possible to use overfitting detector, which I am doing, like this:

```
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=iters, learning_rate=0.03, depth=depth, verbose=True, od_pval=1, od_type='IncToDec', od_wait=20)
model.fit(train_pool, eval_set=validation_pool)

# this code didn't executed
model.save_model(model_name)
```

However, after the overfitting occurs, I've got my Python script interrupted, prematurely stopped, pick any phrase you want, and save model part didn't get executed, which leads to a lot of waisted time and no results in the end. I didn't get any stacktrace.

Is there any possibility to handle it in CatBoost and save hours of fitting work?

Comment: Could you give more info about why and how your python script got killed?

Comment: i expect that this is what overfitting detector has been doing. Not sure, that I fully grasp what you expect me to answer

Comment: Stack trace, for example. What does it mean "killed"?

Comment: what do you mean by `I've got my Python script killed` I would expect that an error was raised. ?

Comment: okay, may be I should rephrase it. I didn't get any stack trace, my script just got interrupted, ended prematurely, pick any word you want. If I would have an error, of course I would paste it here. I'm pretty much sure, it's something with the library (CatBoost), that I'm using

Comment: what data size are we talking about and is it a data specific problem so if you try on another dataset does it work

Comment: @ErroriSalvo data isn't that big, but it's rather computation that are expensive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code. It will save the model no matter what happens in the try block.

```
try:
    model.fit(X, y)
finally:
    model.save_model()
```

Comment: tested it, and it works, even though, at first I thanked it was killed again

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know how catboost work but i would like to share a different way to save/store your trained data maybe it could help

```
import pickle
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=iters, learning_rate=0.03, depth=depth, verbose=True, od_pval=1, od_type='IncToDec', od_wait=20)
model.fit(train_pool, eval_set=validation_pool)
#----To store model----------
filename = 'final_model' # name to store model
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb')) # pickling
#-----To load model------------
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Comment: how the pickle will help me?

Comment: how many no of iterations you are using? and if no of iterations are more than you mentioned in training parameters then it could be because of over fitting...... Pickle is just another way to store model, long time back when i was performing multi class classification i used save_model and it didn't save my classifier so i used pickle and it worked

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with pickle, just train your module and dump it using pickle.

```
 pickle.dump(regr, open("models/svrrbf.sav",'wb'))
```

Further you can use that module to test your inputs.
Hope it helps